# How to close when the websocket closes the connection

Tags: multithreading, go, websocket, goroutine

I have a program that connects to a websocket and I am trying to figure out the best way to keep the program running forever while I have the websocket open.

```
func main() {
    //try to connect to rabbitmq
    rabbitCh, err := rabbitmq.OpenChannel()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer rabbitCh.Close()

    app := Config{
        Rabbit: rabbitCh,
    }

    // https://developer-pro.bitmart.com/en/spot/#public-depth-channel
    ws := bitmart.NewWS(bitmart.Config{WsUrl: bitmart.WS_URL})
    println(ws.isClose)
    err = ws.Connection(func(message string) {
        OnMessage(message, app)
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    channels := []string{
        "spot/trade:BTC_USDT",
    }
    forever := make(chan bool)
    go ws.SubscribeWithoutLogin(channels)

    <-forever
}
```

This runs fine, but runs forever! I can't stop.
The ws object has a ws.isClose boolean that say if the connection is closed or not, but is not public, is it private, and I can not access.

How I can use a channel or maybe a loop, that check if the Websocket is still open and keep the program running?

Here is more info about the go-sdk:
https://github.com/bitmartexchange/bitmart-go-sdk-api/blob/8e4b341b7c2069f99da4ff08f1fb22edf110277d/cloud_ws.go#L33

Bests,
Marcos Issler

1. I tried to use the forever channel but the program got running forever even if I run ctlr+c.
2. I tried to access the ws.isclose to check is there is a connection still open but the object is private and not public. I can change the SDK but I think there is a better solution.